# How to make a Carousel take the space it needs?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm not quite figuring out how to have a carousel between two other items, inside a container, with the carousel NOT having a set height but instead taking the space it requires depending on the size of the content of the active item. Example code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        html: 'abc'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'carousel',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'label',
                                html: 'just need space for one line'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'container',
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'label',
                                html: 'need<br/>space<br/>for<br/>more<br/>lines'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        html: 'def'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

For me it just collapses into nothing (not taking any space at all) if height isn't specified. Using Sencha Touch 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a layout to your container. You can find an [intro to layouts here](http://www.sencha.com/learn/intro-to-layouts-in-sencha-touch-2/)

Basically, you add this in your config :

```
layout:'vbox',
```

The VBox layout positions items horizontally in the container.

Then, in your carousel, just add :

```
flex:1
```

to tell it to take as much space at it can.

[Example here](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#EVqmR)

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm accepting this as it sort of answers the question I've written, although the intention originally was for VARIABLE carousel height, depending on the card content.

Answer (score 0):

Hey @TragedyStruck first you have **understand your screen** where you display your web app. Ok here we go, I did version of your code. The component `Ext.Viewport.getSize().height` take the necessary space for your element. This works for elements NOT fullscreen, if you want fullscreen elements, so you need to programmatically to make a `function`.

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.MyContainer', {
   extend: 'Ext.Container',
   xtype: 'mycontainer1',

   config: {
      scrollable: true,
      items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html: 'abc'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'carousel',
            style: 'background-color: red',
            height: Ext.Viewport.getSize().height,
            renderTo: document.body,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            html: 'just need space for one line'
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'label',
                            html: 'need<br/>space<br/>for<br/>more<br/>lines'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html: 'def'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html: 'ghi'
                }
            ]
        }

     ]
  }
});
```

**I hope this helps. :)**

[image]